With changing implicitHeight to height popup is not shown
in this code my popup gets height and is displayed correctly:
popup: Popup {
    id: _popup
    y: _comboBox.height
    width: _comboBox.width
    implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
    padding: 0
    background: Rectangle {
        radius: DpiSettings.scaling(8)
        color: _comboBox.backgroundColor
    }


    contentItem: ListView {
        width: parent.width
        implicitHeight: Math.min(contentHeight+spacing, _comboBox.popupHeight)
        clip: true
        model: _comboBox.delegateModel

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
            maskSource: Rectangle {
                width: _popup.width
                height: _popup.height
                radius: DpiSettings.scaling(8)
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded
        }
    }
}

but if I change the implicitHeight property to heigth, then the height of the popup becomes 0, why is that? Maybe I don't understand the implicitHeight logic very well, how does it work under the hood?
popup: Popup {
    id: _popup
    y: _comboBox.height
    width: _comboBox.width
    implicitHeight: contentItem.height
    padding: 0
    background: Rectangle {
        radius: DpiSettings.scaling(8)
        color: _comboBox.backgroundColor
    }


    contentItem: ListView {
        width: parent.width
        height: Math.min(contentHeight+spacing, _comboBox.popupHeight)
        clip: true
        model: _comboBox.delegateModel

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: OpacityMask {
            maskSource: Rectangle {
                width: _popup.width
                height: _popup.height
                radius: DpiSettings.scaling(8)
            }
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded
        }
    }
}


From guessing, it appears your attempting to customize a ComboBox with a DelegateModel. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
